# Como pegar a porcentagem total e individual e por campo em ASP Classico

Tags: mysql, asp

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

Meu DB (em MySQL) tem 1 milhão de usuários, sendo que deste são divididos em 3 categorias de cadastro: Masculino, Feminino e Transexual. O objetivo é categorizar da seguinte forma.

Exemplo:

Total 1.400.005 Usuários

Masculino - 30%

feminino - 50%

Trans - 20%

Na tabela está assim

01 | Maria da silva  | 24 anos | Feminino 
02 | Joao da silva   | 20 anos | Masculino 
03 | Vanusa da silva | 25 anos | Transexual

Comment: assim, na mesma coluna separado por ponto e virgula?

Comment: Ola, não, este foi um exemplo para entendimento mais fácil, os dados estao dentro de uma base mysql. com este exemplo eu pego todos os dados da tabela (SELECT COUNT(id) AS total from usuários) fica assim: 1.400.005. Neste caso eu pego todos os usuários. Agora quero pegar de uma tabela chamada Sexo, preciso pegar a quantidade de cada um dos itens(Trans, Feminino e Masculino) e fazer a porcentagem, se possivel em um único comando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conte o número da cada gênero e o total geral dos registros:

```
set rs=conn.execute("select count(*) as num_total,count(case when gen = 'masculino' then gen end) as num_masc,count(case when gen = 'feminino' then gen end) as num_femi,count(case when gen = 'trans' then gen end) as num_trans from tabela")
num_masc = rs("num_masc") 'total de masculino
num_femi = rs("num_femi") 'total de feminino
num_trans = rs("num_trans") 'total de trans
num_total = rs("num_total") 'total de registros
rs.close:set rs=nothing
```

Com essas informações, basta você aplicar a porcentagem no HTML:

```
    Total: <%=formatnumber(num_total,0)%>
   <br>
    Total masculino: <%=num_masc%> (<%=formatnumber((cdbl(num_masc)*100)/cdbl(num_a),2)%>%)<br>
    Total feminino: <%=num_femi%> (<%=formatnumber((cdbl(num_femi)*100)/cdbl(num_a),2)%>%)<br>
    Total trans: <%=num_trans%> (<%=formatnumber((cdbl(num_trans)*100)/cdbl(num_a),2)%>%)
```

Obs.: O "2" em `formatnumber` irá mostrar 2 decimais após vírgula. Você pode alterar caso queira mostrar mais ou menos decimais.

Comment: David Samm Seu cenário foi exatamente o que eu precisava, somente adaptei para meu BD, mas ajudou 99,9%. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Admitindo que o nome da tabela = tabelax e o nome da coluna seja = sexo, podemos fazer assim:

```
select
    sexo,
    count(*) as totalSexo,
    count(*) / (select count(*) from tabelax) as Percentagem
from tabelax
group by sexo
```

Tabela de exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado:

[image: resultado da query]

Caso queira os resultados em forma de percentual arredondados para 2 casas decimais substitua essa linha

`count(*) / (select count(*) from tabelax) as Percentagem`

por

```
round((count(*) / (select count(*) from tabelax)*100),2) as `%`
```

Ou se preferir não usar `%` como alias da coluna, por

```
round((count(*) / (select count(*) from tabelax)*100),2) as Percentagem
```

Resultado:

[image: resultado arredeondando]

> Round - Retorna um valor numérico, arredondado, para o comprimento ou precisão especificados. 
>   Esta função recebe dois parâmetros: o primeiro deles é o número a ser formatado, e o segundo é o número de casas decimais que o usuário deseja que o valor apresente. Na omissão do segundo parâmetro, o comando arredonda o valor para um inteiro (sem casas decimais).

Answer (score 1):

**ASP** sou leigo, mas você está no caminho certo, tipo assim como no **PHP** creio que não tenha muita diferença.

O que você precisa fazer é o seguinte, em sua **sql query** faça algo tipo:

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(sexo) as total_sex, COUNT(id) as total FROM usuarios GROUP BY sexo';
```

**GROUP BY sexo**, ele agrupa todas as linhas que contém os dados iguais.

**Exempo em PHP**

Acesse o site https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php_mysql_online.php e coloque o código abaixo:

```
<?php
$driver = 'mysql';
$database = "dbname=CODINGGROUND";
$dsn = "$driver:host=localhost;unix_socket=/home/cg/mysql/mysql.sock;$database";

$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';

try {
   $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
   echo "<h2>Database CODINGGROUND Connected<h2>";
}catch(PDOException $e){
   echo "<h1>" . $e->getMessage() . "</h1>";
}
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(sex) as total_sex,COUNT(id) as total, sex FROM users GROUP BY sex';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$TotalRegistros = 0;
$Total['F'] = 0;
$Total['M'] = 0;

echo "<pre>";
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($row = array_shift($rows)){
    $TotalRegistros = ($TotalRegistros + $row['total']);
    $Total[$row['sex']] = $row['total_sex'];
    echo "Total de " . $row['sex'] . ": " .$row['total_sex'];
    echo "<br>";
}

echo "Registros: " . $TotalRegistros . "<br>";
$PorcentagemMulheres = ( $Total['F'] / $TotalRegistros ) * 100;
$PorcentagemHomens = ( $Total['M'] / $TotalRegistros ) * 100;
echo "Porcentagem de Mulheres: " . number_format( $PorcentagemMulheres, 2 ) . '%' . "<br>";
echo "Porcentagem de Homens: " . number_format( $PorcentagemHomens, 2 ) . '%' . "<br>";
?>
```